# Symfony 5 unittest can't fetch entity collection

Tags: phpunit, symfony5

my collection is empty while I try to access it in a unittest. In dev && prod env it is accessable as aspected.

One customerOrder can have multiple invoices and one invoice can have one customerOrder.

```
class CustomerOrderServiceTest extends KernelTestCase
{
use RefreshDatabaseTrait;

public function testAdd()
{
    self::bootKernel();
    $container = self::$container;

    $orderRepository = $container->get(CustomerOrderRepository::class);
    $customerOrder = $orderRepository->find(1);
    foreach ($customerOrder->getInvoices() as $invoice) {
        dump('Invoice id: ' . $invoice->getId());
    }
    dump('Invoice count: ' . $customerOrder->getInvoices()->count());

    $invoiceRepository = $container->get(InvoiceRepository::class);
    $invoice = $invoiceRepository->find(1);
    dump('Order id: ' . $invoice->getCustomerOrder()->getId());
    dump('Invoice count: ' . $invoice->getCustomerOrder()->getInvoices()->count());
}
}
```

The Output is

> Testing Project Test Suite
> ^ "Invoice count: 0"
> ^ "Order id: 1"
> ^ "Invoice count: 0"

So the Order is accessable over the invoice but not the other way around.

The entities:

```
/**
* CustomerOrder
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\CustomerOrderRepository")
*/
class CustomerOrder{
/**
 * @var Collection
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Invoice", mappedBy="customerOrder", cascade={"persist"}, fetch="EAGER")
 */
    private $invoices;
}


/**
* Invoice
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\InvoiceRepository")
* @ORM\Table(uniqueConstraints={@ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="number",columns={"number", "owner"})})
*/
class Invoice{
/**
 * @var CustomerOrder
 */
  private $customerOrder;
}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!-- https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html -->
<phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="bin/.phpunit/phpunit.xsd"
         colors="true"
         bootstrap="tests/bootstrap.php"
>
    <php>
        <ini name="error_reporting" value="-1"/>
        <server name="APP_ENV" value="test" force="true"/>
        <server name="SHELL_VERBOSITY" value="-1"/>
        <server name="SYMFONY_PHPUNIT_REMOVE" value=""/>
        <server name="SYMFONY_PHPUNIT_VERSION" value="7.5"/>

        <!-- ###+ symfony/framework-bundle ### -->
        <env name="APP_ENV" value="test" force="true"/>
        <env name="APP_SECRET" value="*****"/>
        <!-- ###- symfony/framework-bundle ### -->
    </php>

    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Project Test Suite">
            <directory>tests</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>

    <filter>
        <whitelist processUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist="true">
            <directory suffix=".php">src</directory>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>

    <listeners>
        <listener class="Symfony\Bridge\PhpUnit\SymfonyTestsListener" />
    </listeners>
</phpunit>
```

Comment: Can you post your phpunit.xml.dist file?

Comment: I have added the file

Comment: If someone have the same problem, It works by calling the entity manager instead of loading the repository. Would be nice if I vould use the repository though.
```
$kernel->getContainer()
            ->get('doctrine')
            ->getManager()
            ->getRepository(CustomerOrder::class)
```